# Getting a JsonSerializationException when trying to deserialize PlayerStats

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I want to insert into my class data from JSON but I got a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`.
My `PlayerStats` class is good, I think, and I don't know why it's not working.
I can download and print JSON to the console but my code stops working at the point when I try to deserialize.  I tried to add settings to deserialize but it's still not working.

Here is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace DiscordBot
{
    class Osu
    {
        public string _nickname;
        private string _key = "key";

        public class PlayerStats
        {
            [JsonProperty("user_id")]
            public int UserId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("username")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count300")]
            public int Count300 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count100")]
            public int Count100 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count50")]
            public int Count50 { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("playcount")]
            public int PlayCount { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ranked_score")]
            public long RankedScore { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("total_score")]
            public long TotalScore { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("pp_rank")]
            public int PpRank { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("level")]
            public double Level { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("pp_raw")]
            public double RawPp { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("accuracy")]
            public double Accuracy { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count_rank_ss")]
            public int CountRankSs { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count_rank_ssh")]
            public int CoundRankSsh { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count_rank_s")]
            public int CountRankS { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count_rank_sh")]
            public int CountRankSh { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("count_rank_a")]
            public int CountRankA { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("country")]
            public string Country { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("pp_country_rank")]
            public int PpCountryRank { get; set; }
        }

        public PlayerStats GetUserStats()
        {
            string json = string.Empty;
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerStats>(json);
            try
            {
                string url = @"https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user";
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.QueryString.Add("k", _key);
                    wc.QueryString.Add("u", _nickname);
                    wc.QueryString.Add("m", "0");
                    json = wc.DownloadString(url);
                    Console.WriteLine(json);
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerStats>(json);
                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Osu Error: " + ex.Status);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "user_id":"10415972"
        ,"username":"iGruby"
        ,"count300":"851431"
        ,"count100":"15449 6"
        ,"count50":"19825"
        ,"playcount":"7129"
        ,"ranked_score":"453511877"
        ,"total_score" :"2735863526"
        ,"pp_rank":"147461"
        ,"level":"74.5611"
        ,"pp_raw":"1642.73"
        ,"accuracy" :"94.46521759033203"
        ,"count_rank_ss":"13"
        ,"count_rank_ssh":"2"
        ,"count_rank_s":"3 6"
        ,"count_rank_sh":"13"
        ,"count_rank_a":"65"
        ,"country":"PL"
        ,"pp_country_rank":"77 20"
        ,"events":[]
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the JSON you are trying to deserialize?  Also, what is the message of the exception you are getting?

Comment: You are passing an empty string into DeserializeObject  on the second line of GetUserStats

Comment: Please provide json @Robert

Comment: Agree with those above, definitely need a json sample to work with.

Comment: @ivcubr lets wait for json and then try to find out solution

Comment: @D-johnAnshani Added the json string

Comment: @RobertArktyk find my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this Tested Answer from the file I have loaded your json and DeserializeObject check my model also and how I am DeserializeObject

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText("D://readjson.txt");
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(data);
        }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string count300 { get; set; }
        public string count100 { get; set; }
        public string count50 { get; set; }
        public string playcount { get; set; }
        public string ranked_score { get; set; }
        public string total_score { get; set; }
        public string pp_rank { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string pp_raw { get; set; }
        public string accuracy { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_ss { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_ssh { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_s { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_sh { get; set; }
        public string count_rank_a { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string pp_country_rank { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public List<object> events { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: @RobertArktyk approve answer also now if its help you

Comment: @D-johnAnshani Can you annotate your answer to explain what was failing in the original please? :)

Comment: while DeserializeObject its deserialize object but we have an array, not an object that why problem is occur and i have also update model

Answer (score 0):

Pp_country_rank and count_rank_s contains a space. This is trying to be parsed to an integer.

```
    "count_rank_s":"3 6"
    ,"count_rank_sh":"13"
    ,"count_rank_a":"65"
    ,"country":"PL"
    ,"pp_country_rank":"77 20"
```

Comment: @RobertArktyk check my answer

Comment: @slitCanvas its a string so problem is not with that

Comment: @D-johnAnshani it wasn't in the C# class.